# Is it possible to convert a PHP function's parameter list to an array?

Tags: php, arrays, function, parameters, arguments

Suppose I have a function:

```
function my_function($a, $b, $c) {
    ...
}
```

I want to be able to play with my parameter list as if it were an array - as with here, using a fake `$parameter_list` variable:

```
function my_function($a, $b, $c) {
    foreach ($parameter_list as $value) {
        print $value."\n";
    }
    ...
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just call [`func_get_args()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php).

It's normally used for user-defined functions that have a variable number of arguments but there's no reason you can't use it for a "normal" function.

This returns a numerically-indexed array of function arguments. There is no way of returning the parameter names.

Comment: hm nice - didn't know about this.

Comment: Yeah, there are a ton of inbuilt functions in PHP. I'm still surprised at some I find.